# Cmake - Packaging a mac OS bundle app and install it. But Can i disable the relocation?

Tags: macos, cmake, cpack

I created an .app bundle in Mac OS and trying to distribute it. But the installer package have an option to relocate the package to an existing .app file. I can't seem to find the option to disable that in CPack. Do I have to live with that option being on?